# Input data in python in a BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am starting to work with GCP due to several solutions integrated in a single location. With that, create a data warehouse in BigQuery. Create as tables and import the associated data directly from the platform, and start consuming through an API. Now, you are starting to implement in Python, a way of imputing new data to the bank, however, you must send a csv table that is not already formed in the table and columns, but you do not know exactly how to do this.

```
Table example:
create "data" table (
    id PRIMARY KEY INTEGER,
    project_ID INTEGER,
    installation date
    forecast date,
    meeting,
    configuration date
    VARCHAR update (100)
)
```

```
CSV example:

data.csv:
id | project_id | installation | forecast | withdrawal | date | configuration | update
```

Do you know how I can do this when recording in python in a bigquery?

Comment: Your post is difficult to understand. Do you want to import the CSV into the BigQuery table with Python?

Comment: exactly, but I don't know how to do it via bigquery api

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table

Comment: OMG! Thank you very much!!

Comment: That approach requires first storing the csv in Google Cloud Storage but I think you will have to do that regardless unless you use the web UI

Comment: Yes, Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would use Pandas to read csv data and then store data to BigQuery. Example code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('your_csv.csv', delimiter='|')
df.to_gbq(destination_table='your_table_name', project_id='your_bq_project', if_exists='replace')
```

This code works in the case you initially set up your credentials.

Answer (score 1):

To sum-up the contributors efforts in the comments:

Bigquery offers a variety of certain ways to [load](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data) data. To work directly with [Bigquery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest) preferring favorite programming language consider to choose the particular [client library API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries).

Specifically for [Python API client](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-python) library and the file in CVS format the data can be loaded:

- From Cloud Storage(GCS bucket) throughout Bigquery job, link
  [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table);
- From the file residing on local machine, link [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#loading_data_from_a_local_data_source);